# Creating resources dynamically in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to create a chef recipe that will dynamically create resources based on the contents of a yaml file downloaded from a git repository with my application source code. I have this so far:

```
git "/home/a_user/#{ node[:my_node][:application] }" do
  repository node[:my_node][:git_repository]
  revision node[:my_node][:git_branch]
  action :sync
  user "a_user"
  group "a_user"
end

require 'yaml'

ruby_block "load the process into the node" do
  block do
     yml = YAML::load(File.open("/home/a_user/#{node[:my_node][:application]}/processes.yml"))
     node.set[:my_node][:worker][:processes] = yml[:processes]
  end
  subscribes :create, "git[/home/a_user/#{ node[:my_node][:application] }]" :immediately
end



node[:my_node][:worker][:processes].each do | name, cmd |
   supervisor_service name do
     command "bash -c \"source /home/a_user/.profile && #{ cmd }\""
     action :enable
   end   
 end 

 service "supervisor" do
    action :restart
 end
```

The yaml file format is:

```
processes:
    process_a: python myscript.py --a
    process_b: python myscript.py --b
```

However when I execute it, the value of `node[:my_node][:worker][:processes]` is empty in the compile phase so the supervisor resources aren't executed in the execution phase.

Can someone give me a pointer on how to make this work? I missing something obvious or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: You may want to check out my [dialects branch](https://github.com/coderanger/chef/tree/dialects) and the [proposal behind it](https://gist.github.com/coderanger/a6e0c627d349f0712dcc). This would allow authoring recipes in Yaml if you make a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the attribute during the compilation phase:

```
git "/home/a_user/#{ node[:my_node][:application] }" do
  repository node[:my_node][:git_repository]
  revision node[:my_node][:git_branch]
  action :nothing
  user "a_user"
  group "a_user"
end.run_action(:sync)

ruby_block "load the process into the node" do
  block do
     yml = YAML::load(File.open("/home/a_user/#{node[:my_node][:application]}/processes.yml"))
     node.set[:my_node][:worker][:processes] = yml[:processes]
  end
  subscribes :create, "git[/home/a_user/#{ node[:my_node][:application] }]" :immediately
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:create)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this then requires a lot of other resources to be run during the compile phase as well which is starting to get quite messy and doesn't feel particularly 'chefy'.

Comment: Have you tried using `lazy` on the `ruby_block`? Something like `block lazy { { yml = YAML::... } }`. More info here: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation